# A convex function is "usually" subdifferentiable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space, and let $f:X\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ be a proper, convex, lower semicontinuous function, whose effective domain $D:=f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is compact. Let $S\subseteq D$ be the set of points at which $f$ is subdifferentiable.

My question is somewhat vague: What results are there that say $S$ constitutes "most of" $D$? One example of such a result is the Brøndsted-Rockafellar theorem, which says $S$ is dense in $D$ whenever $X$ is a Banach space.

Ideally, I'd like to know any results guaranteeing $S$ is most of $D$ in some sense other than topological (e.g. measure-theoretic). Any pointers to such results would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can suggest some keywords in connection to your last paragraph. One generalisation of measure zero sets to more general vector spaces is given by sets called *shy*; a set that isn't shy is called *prevalent*.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I would love a result giving sufficient conditions for $D\setminus S$ to be shy. But I'd also love results saying $S$ is "most of" $D$ in other senses---a measure theoretic sense was just one example.

Comment: Sorry, I have a correction to make to my previous comment: instead it should have said that a set is called *prevalent* if its complement is shy.